# Grave (`) is marked as illegal token

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to transfer a node program I created locally to an EC2 server via Cloud9, and I have already manually replaced all of the (req,res) => {} statements because it didn't accept that. However, now it's giving me

```
console.log(`foo ${bar}`)
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:945:3
```

It works fine on my local server and it runs fine here too, even without nodejs.

```js
var bar = "bar"
console.log(`foo ${bar}`)
```

The version of node is v13.9.0 and it was installed via nvp.
Anyone know why this is happening? I really don't want to go through and convert all the strings with `

Comment: don't see anything wrong with that specific line. May be post the full code.

Comment: Template literals have been supported on node since V4. Is there a chance that you copy and pasted that backtick in there and it's not actually a backtick?

Comment: So if it did not support fat arrow and now string template literals, sounds like somehting is not allowing ES6

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple versions of nodejs installed and the version is getting confused

Comment: Are you certain that you are, in fact, running v13.9.0? nvm and nvp are great, but you can set the current version of Node to whatever you want using them and still end up running a different version.  I'd suggest running a simple ES5-only script in it and outputting the Node version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I figured out that cloud9 automatically installs nodejs, just not the right version. It installs 10.19.0, while the current latest version is 13.10.0. I installed the latest version, but the default was still 10.19.0. For anyone else having this problem, do

```
nvm ls
```

to list your installed node versions, then use

```
nvm alias default 13.10.0 (replace with whatever version you want)
```

Comment: That doesn't quite explain why the back-tick was causing a problem. Template literals should work fine in both version 10 and 13.